# Some properties of elements of the finite field GF(q)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the finite field $GF(q)$ and an element $w$ of order $n$ which is an $n$th root of unity in this field.

Could someone give me explanation or reference to the following questions regarding properties of the elements of $GF(q)$:

1. Why does $w$ exist only if $n$ divides $q-1$?
2. Why is $w^r$ a zero of the left side for all $r$? Actually what does it mean $w$ to be a zero of the left side for all $r$? This is the context: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w^{(k-i)j},$$ where $i$ is fixed. It seems that $r$ is $k-i$. I can't understand the conclusion - "Hence for all $r \neq 0 \pmod n$, $w^r$ is a zero of the last term."
3. In any field, $x^n - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + ... + x + 1)$. Why is this statement true?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand what is meant by your question 2.  The left side of what?

Comment: @Eric - Eric, I updated the question.

Comment: Please make sure I've written that  double sum correctly. You might also want to consult the following website to make your questions more readable in the future. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly write down this recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $(GF \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace)^{\times} $ is a cyclic group of order $q-1$, so this is an application of Lagrange theorem

2) This point depends on $i$ , infact if $ i \leq n-1 $ $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w^{(k-i)j} = \sum_{k = 0, k \neq i}^{n-1} \frac{(\omega^{k-i})^n -1}{\omega^{k-i} -1} + \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1} 1 = \sum_{k = 0, k \neq i}^{n-1} \frac{(\omega^{n})^{k-i} -1}{\omega^{k-i} -1} + n = \sum_{k = 0, k \neq i}^{n-1} 0+ n = n $$

If $ i > n-1 $ the sum is $0$.

This remains true if you substitute $\omega$ with $\omega^r$, because $\omega^r$ is still a $n$-th root of unit.

3) Here you simply have to calculate, in every field you can do sums and products

Answer (score 2):

$GF(q)$ contains $0$ and a bunch of units.  Any time you address a question about multiplicative properties, you are working in the multiplicative subgroup, $GF(q)^\times$.  You'll notice that many arguments split as: "for an element that is a unit, ...argument..., giving result.  Note also that for zero, the same result holds", reflecting this partition of elements.

Restricting attention to $GF(q)^\times$, $\langle w \rangle = \{1,w,w^2, w^3, \dots, w^{n-1}\}$ is the subgroup generated by $w$, so is subject to Lagrange's Theorem, which addresses question 1.

I am unable to understand your question 2.

Your third question has answer "yes".  Fields have addition and multiplication and therefore the expression on the right evaluates to the same expression as on the left.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Question 2 is related to Codes based on the Fourier Transform. Maybe I had to add the definitions and the properties of this transformation, I'm sure it would have been clearer then. I can't vote up because of a reputation deficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I hazard an educated guess that the somewhat unclear part 2 actually means the following. Let $w$ be of order $n$ in a finite field. Let $r\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$ be some integer. Then in $GF(q)$ we have
$$
S(r):=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w^{rj}=0.
$$

**Proof.** That sum is geometric with ratio of successive terms equal to $w^r$. The assumption about $r$ means that $w^r\neq1$. Therefore the formula for a geometric sum works, and
$$
S(r)=\frac{1-w^{rn}}{1-w^r}=\frac{1-1}{1-w^r}=0.
$$

Comment: This inner sum just appear in so many contexts and applications of finite fields. Coding theory, DFT over a finite field,... Thus my level of confidence in guessing that this is what the OP's source meant is relatively high. Of course, I've been proven wrong many times.

Comment: And, of course, when $r\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, then the sum is a bunch of ones, and adds up to $n-1$.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you very much for the help. It seems less complicated than what I thought it is. I can't vote up because of a reputation deficiency and also marked the answer from WLOG as correct because the person answered to all three questions in the post.

Comment: That's ok, @e2l3n! I have enough rep as it is. I only wanted to augment Eric Towers' answer as he seemed to be unwilling to make that guess. If this explanation clears up the point in your source, then that's the main thing.

Comment: And yes! The context of question 2 is related to codes based on the Fourier transform.